# Why is this Powershell function that should return a string prepending a digit and a space to the expected return value?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a PS script which needs to generate several ephemeral files which need to be cleaned up before the script exits.  To that end, I wrote a pair of functions:

```
# Initialize the list of temporary files
$junkFiles = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

# Generate a random string with 8 characters, containing only
# alpha characters.
function New-RandomString() {
    $random = Get-Random -Count 8 -InputObject (65..90 + 97..122) | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ }
    $randomString = -join $random
    return $randomString
}

# Generates a random file name having the specified extension
# Also adds the file name to the list of file names which have been created
function New-Filename($extension) {
    $fileName = "$(New-RandomString).$extension"
    $junkFiles.Add($fileName)
    return $fileName
}

# Iterates through the list of created file names and removes them
function Remove-JunkFiles() {
    foreach ($file in $junkFiles) {
        Remove-Item -Path $file -Force
    }
    $junkFiles = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
}
```

As a test, I added the following main body, which should create 3 files and then delete them:

```
# Test script (creates 3 file names)
for ($i=0; $i -le 3; $i++) {
    $foo = $(New-Filename 'txt')
    Write-Host "File name: $foo"
    New-Item -ItemType file -Path $foo
}

Remove-JunkFiles
```

The output looks like this:

```
File name: 0 OHwnDEMP.txt


    Directory: C:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/17/2024   2:01 PM              0 0
-a----        1/17/2024   2:01 PM              0 OHwnDEMP.txt
File name: 1 IHeoLJPd.txt
-a----        1/17/2024   2:01 PM              0 1
-a----        1/17/2024   2:01 PM              0 IHeoLJPd.txt
File name: 2 EFMLvoRn.txt
-a----        1/17/2024   2:01 PM              0 2
-a----        1/17/2024   2:01 PM              0 EFMLvoRn.txt
File name: 3 lPoGWXyp.txt
-a----        1/17/2024   2:01 PM              0 3
-a----        1/17/2024   2:01 PM              0 lPoGWXyp.txt
```

So, for some reason, the `New-Filename` function is appending the index where the file name was added to the `$junkFiles` list to the output. This is also causing the `New-Item` cmdlet to create 2 files instead of 1 (the first being named with just the digit).

Any idea why on earth I'm getting this output from `New-Filename`?

Also, note that when I iterate through `$junkFiles` the values do *not* contain the prepending digit + space.

Comment: There's always the `[System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()` that will just generate temp file names for you.

Comment: you need to `$null = $junkFiles.Add($fileName)` or any other redirection technique of your choice. `.Add` from ArrayList outputs the index in the collection where the item was added.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thank you! If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: It has been asked before, the linked answer explains this issue in detail

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon The answer you linked to explains why, but it wouldn't help someone who was in my position since it doesn't describe a problem. I don't agree with my question being closed as duplicate, and I've edited my title as such.

Comment: Ok, I'll reopen it. I'm certain there are other answer that share a very similar issue as in your question but I'm too lazy to search for one 